# javascript error { [native code] }

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to do some basic javascript and am getting "native code" instead of what I want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
document.write(today  + "<br />");
//document.write(today.length  + "<br />"); - was getting "undefined"
//document.write(today[0]  + "<br />"); - was getting "undefined"

document.write(today.getMonth  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getMonth  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getFullYear  + "<br />");

</script>
```

output was:

```
Fri Jan 13 14:13:01 EST 2012
function getMonth() { [native code] } 
function getDay() { [native code] } 
function getFullYear() { [native code] }
```

what I want is to get the current Month, Day, Year and put it into an array variable that I will be able to call later on. I'm not getting far because of this native code. Can someone tell me what it is and hopefully, more importantly I can complete this project? Thank you for your time and help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: For exercise purposes you could have your script within <PRE> and use document.writeln

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `getMonth` and the rest are functions, not properties, when you call just `today.getMonth` you are getting a reference to the actual function. But, if you execute it using parenthesis, you get the actual result.

Your code should be:

```
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getFullYear()  + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the parenthesis`()`.

```
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getFullYear()  + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />"); // notice the ()'s to invoke the function
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getFullYear()  + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

`getMonth` and `getFullYear` are functions, so you need to invoke them. Note the parentheses:

```
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getMonth()  + "<br />");
document.write(today.getFullYear()  + "<br />");
```

As you have it, it's printing the string representations of the functions, not the functions' values.